# How to backup and restore Empathy accounts and password in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: backup, 12.04, empathy, restore

There is no documentation on how to backup and then restore your empathy accounts.
The other thread is very vague and does not help

Answer (score 1):

Accounts settings are saved in `~/.mission-control/accounts/accounts.cfg` 
If you also want your saved passwords for accounts, you'll need to copy your GNOME keyring as well, which is in `~/.gnome2/keyrings`.